# Execute a block of code after certain time in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I would like to execute a block of code in a thread after a mount of time.

In the thread:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("it is running");
    while (true) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastEdit) {
            System.out.println("DELETE");
            timerStart(12000);
        }
    }
}

public static void timerStart(int time) {
    lastEdit = System.currentTimeMillis() + time;
}
```

In this block of code, the System.out.println("DELETE") will execute after 12s.
However, I would also call timeStart function in another code, which is the following

```
anotherThread.timerStart(12000);
```

When I call this function, I expect the lastEdit will increase 12000 milli sec. However, it doesn't work.
May I know why and how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect what's happening is that your program is spending all its resources comparing `Ssytem.currentTimeMillis()` to `lastEdit`, and nothing else gets a chance to run.  You might need a `Thread.sleep` somewhere in there.  Also, make sure that `lastEdit` is declared `volatile`.

Comment: Yeah, "hot" waiting ... isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you're really trying to do, but changing your `run()` function so that it spends most of its time "sleeping" might improve the performance of your program:

```java
public void run() {
    System.out.println("it is running");
    while(true) {
        long timeUntilDelete = lastEdit - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (timeUntilDelete > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeUntilDelete);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                ...What you do here is up to you...
            }
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("DELETE");
        timerStart(12000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so you could be using `ScheduledExecutorService`, take a look to oracle docs, you will find an example, I believe solves your problem

Comment: I have searched about scheduleAtFixedRate. But what I want to do is initially delay execution for 10 seconds. And if I do something else in another program, it will restart the timer and execute the code after 10s.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question, I guess you are using `lastEdit` as static var, you may want to add `volatile` keyword to the var, so that the threads will access to the real value of your var.. take a look at [volatile keyword](https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile)

Comment: Please note: this community wants quality answers. Telling people "go read some documentation about X" isn't that. Seriously: if you dont want to spend the time to write a proper answer, then write a comment. Otherwise, invest a few minutes and write an answer that deserves to be called "answer".